# Windows Service does not start automatically on Windows 7

Tags: windows-services

I made a Windows Service application, set its properties to start automatically, using system account.

Windows 10 behavior: Starts as expected. On every system restart.

Windows 7 behavior: Does not start. No error / warning message in any log. Can be started by administrative user. Starts immediately.

I would understand an error occurs when the system is trying to start the service, but then again where's the log entry? Why the service can be started manually? Then, what's the weirdest part here: why does it work on Windows 10?

BTW, my service's OnStart is empty except `base.OnStart(args)`.

The only log entry I get is System log:

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the MY_SERVICE to connect.

Important fact: The service starts when set to "Delayed Start". But this is not acceptable for me. The service is to be started ASAP, "Delayed Start" occurs way too late for my needs.

How to make my service compatible with Windows 7, what may be the possible cause of service not starting automatically on Windows 7, but staring correctly on Windows 10?

My service uses .NET Framework 4.6.1 and it is installed on my test Windows 7 VM.

Comment: Windows should log an error when a service doesn't start. Please make sure that you are looking in the right area of the Event Viewer: https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/event-viewer-troubleshoot-windows-services/

Comment: @CoreTech I've double checked it. There is no application error either in Application log, or service's own log. I experimented with placing a custom log entry as a first instruction in `OnStart` override - it does't get executed. It seems like service's `OnStart` method is not even invoked at all. However the service handles `SessionChange` event, but this works fine since the service is started manually. I can switch between sessions, log on and log off users - everything works since starting manually.

Comment: How about in the Windows Logs > System area? Look for events where the source is the Service Control Manager.

Comment: There is only one event, the one I pasted. About timeout. It seems like `Service.OnStart` is not even called.